# How to style frame same as eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, look-and-feel

Is there any `Look and Feel`, `Library`, etc., for imlementing the `user interface` windows similar to `eclipse` windows?
e.g., I used `javax.swing` and I write a `JFrame`, but its style is not the same as eclipse UI wizard.

---

**My frame:**

[image: My frame]

**The eclipse frame:**

[image: eclipse frame]

Comment: For me it looks pretty close, what elements do you expect to look different?

Comment: Eclipse uses SWT not Swing. SWT uses native controls and looks much more like a native app on which ever platform you run it on.

Comment: @Zabuza e.g., the help icon is shown at the bottom of the UI. The style of all elements such as button, etc.,  are same as eclipse elements.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you very much indeed for your kind help. would you please give me a reference to learn how can I create a frame using SWT?

Comment: SWT is a completely different GUI system from Swing. You would have to completely rewrite your app to use it. [SWT tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks again. It seems if I use SWT also I need to set the size and color of buttons and other elements by myself. Is it true? Isn't there  source of eclipse wizards?